# Finding and replacing a pair of characters in a string with another pair of characters in that string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, swap

I'm new to Python, but want to figure out how to take a string and swap pairs of characters around. Let's say we have the string 
'HELLO__WORLD' and want to switch the HE in HELLO with __. So that the string now looks like '__LLOHEWORLD' How could that be done? Does it have anything to do with .pop and .append? Or perhaps if, elif, else functions could be used? Maybe to begin with, .index is needed to find the characters that the user specifies need to be swapped?

I honestly have no idea really where to begin.

Comment: `string.replace("HE","__")` or `string.replace("HELLO__WORLD","__LLO__WORLD")`

Answer (score 1):

`.pop()` and `.append()` are `list` methods.

Read up on lists and data structures https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

You could solve that by using `replace`

eg.

```
hello = 'HELLO WORLD'
new_hello = hello.replace('HE', '_')
```

Comment: What if I convert the string to a list? Could I use .pop() and .append() then?

Comment: Yes. If you cast the string to a list you can use .pop() and .append().

Comment: But how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned in other answers, [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) is definitely what you want to use:

```
my_string = "HELLO__WORLD"
replaced = my_string.replace("HE","__")
print(replaced) #shows __LLO__WORLD
```

Although this may not be enough if `"HE"` is present elsewhere in the string and should not be replaced:

```
my_string = "HE SAID HELLO_WORLD"
replaced = my_string.replace("HE","__")
print(replaced) #shows __ SAID __LLO_WORLD
```

in which case you would want to specify the entire part that you want to replace:

```
my_string = "HE SAID HELLO_WORLD"
replaced = my_string.replace("HELLO_WORLD","__LLO__WORLD")
print(replaced) #shows HE SAID __LLO_WORLD
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [replace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) string method:

```
s = 'HELLO__WORLD'
s = s.replace('HE', '__')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the index of substrings you want to swap, you can turn your string to list, swap with slice, then turn it back to string.

```
s = "HELLO__WORLD"
# "HE" is at [0:2], "__" is at [5:7]
s = list(s)
s[0:2], s[5:7] = s[5:7], s[0:2]
s = "".join(s)
print(s) # prints __LLOHEWORLD
```

For finding the index of substring, you can use `.find`:

```
s = "HELLO__WORLD"
s.find("__") #returns 5
```

Comment: Thanks Miles, this really helps.